# How to use autodesk viewer api to view .dxf files on my website?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have around 200 .dxf files on my server. I would like to integrate the autodesk-forge viewer so that people coming to my website can view the drawings? I do not see any example as such online which can help me in that? Do you guys have any examples which can assist me in this?

I do not want to upload the files on the cloud and use the embed link rather I just want to use the viewer api and pass my .dxf files from my server to view those on my website.

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible, the Autodesk Forge Viewer requires you to upload the file on the Autodesk storage and use the Model Derivative API to prepare your DXF files to be viewed in the Viewer. You do not need to keep the DXF on the Autodesk storage after the process, but this is a required step.

If you follow this [tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/), you will be able to see you DXF files onlines. All resources are protected, but if you want to delete the seed file (aka the DXF file), you need to call this [endpoint](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-DELETE/) at the end of the tutorial steps.

Comment: hello Cyrille, Thanks this makes sense. Do you have a working example which I can follow? the tutorial does not give me an option to download the files and view a working example.

Comment: I would use this sample to process files: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs
and this example to make my website: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-nodejs-tutorial